# How to pass arguments on cron in Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am trying to run a cron job in Google App Engine with a parameter but cannot send any parameters in cron.yaml. Anyone know how to send parameters in cron.yaml?

```
handlers:
- url: /testing
  script: testing.php
```

What I want to send is testing.php?testing=12345, but the script won't run if I write it like that.

I read this:

[How to pass arguments to a python cron task on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014909/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-python-cron-task-on-google-app-engine)

.. but I didnt understand much of it as it was for Python.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you define your WSGI application ?

Comment: You mean this? 

`application: xxx`
`version: 1`
`runtime: php`
`api_version: 1`
`threadsafe: yes`

Answer (score 5):

`cron:
 - description: Testing Cron
   url: /testing.php?testing=12345
   schedule: every 60 mins`

According to Google ( https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/cron ) the above should be the correct syntax, note the use of cron instead of handlers.

I'd like to know why you are using a query string parameter?  If this is to restrict access you could easily do this by adding admin login only:

`cron:
 - description: Testing Cron
   url: /testing.php?testing=12345
   schedule: every 60 mins
   login: admin`

Alternatively if you are convinced that adding a query string to the end of your url is not working you can always use different urls for differing tasks...